# Что влияет на скорость вывода полигонов в OpenGL?

Tags: графика, opengl

Если передавать в шейдер сжатый массив вершин полигонов, распаковывать его, а затем выводить на экран, поможет ли это увеличению производительности, не считая издержек на саму распаковку данных? Ведь мы, по сути, передали меньший объем данных в шейдер.

Немного добавлю. Грубо говоря, вопрос сводится к тому, как передавать в вершинный шейдер информации меньше, а рисовать при этом полигонов больше.

Comment: Простите профана за дурацкий вопрос. При передаче данных в шейдер они реально переписываются из одной части ОЗУ в другую ?

Comment: Обычно работают с так называемыми `Vertex Buffer Object'ами` - коллекциями вершин, которые ускоряют доступ к ним в шейдерах. *Понятно, что эти вершины для отрисовки должны быть скопированы в видеопамять из ОЗУ, т.к у видеокарты доступа к ОЗУ не имеется.*

Comment: С этим ясно. А какие манипуляции можно производить непосредственно в видеопамяти с этими данными, например, копировать/удалять, изменять значения.

Comment: @OpenGLprogrammer Здесь стоит смотреть в сторону проектов типа `OpenCL`, которые позволяют писать более-менее `C`-подобный код для `GPU` кернелов. *В тривиальных случаях можно грузить данные в текстуру, проходиться по ней каким-нибудь шейдером и выгружать эти данные обратно.* Если затраты на разгрузку-погрузку меньше объема работы, то можно получить неслабый прирост. **В общем-то, это же правило распространяется и на `OpenCL`.**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Таким образом вопрос сводится к тому, что можно ли реализовать распаковку ресурсами видеокарты, которая займет меньшее время, чем пересылка неупакованных данных (насколько мне известно видеокарта это специализированный векторно-параллельный процессор).

Интересный вопрос (плюсую).

Comment: Можно ли генерировать в видеопамяти какие угодно значения из вершинного шейдера? Например, передаём в шейдер несколько значений. На основании их генерируем большой объем данных, которые будут занесены в видеопамять, и выводим всё на экран в виде полигонов. Пройдёт ли такой способ?

Comment: *Специально для таких вещей и были придуманы геометрические шейдера*, которые, по сути своей, именно этим и занимаются, только делают это более удобным способом для разработчика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно поинтересоваться, **в каком именно шейдере** вам пригодится набор вершин?

*Вертексный шейдер* работает над одной вершиной, *пиксельный шейдер* - понятно, оперирует на уровне пикселей. *Геометрический шейдер* и так работает с наборами вершин, т.е некоторыми примитивами.

Единственное, что я могу предположить - это то, что для сложных шейдеров *(большей часть, наверно, пиксельных)*, могут пригодится данные о других вершинах, которые необходимо как-то загрузить на `GPU` и обработать для получения нужного эффекта. Но даже в таких случаях эти самые данные чаще всего *записываются в текстуру* и передаются через нее, а не напрямую, т.к получается эффективнее.

Comment: Как вы могли догадаться речь идёт о вершинном шейдере. Количество передаваемых в него данных можно существенно сократить при относительно примитивном сжатии.

Comment: @OpenGLprogrammer Я все еще не понимаю, какие именно данные **о других вершинах** вы собираетесь передавать в вершинный шейдер, и слабо понимаю, как именно вы хотите производить `packing/unpacking`. 


*Но если даже допустить, что у вас все получится, я сомневаюсь, что это хорошая идея, поскольку, будь она хорошей, она бы **давным давно была бы реализована аппаратно***

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, рисовать круг из 11 точек (1 – центр,10 – вокруг)быстрее с GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, чем без него.В одном случае необходимо задать целых 30 вершин, в другом – всего 11, так как каждая лишняя точка, по сути, добавляет один полигон к целой модели. Это, теоретически, должно сказаться и на скорость выполнения шейдера. Экономия получается существенной. Отсюда я строю дальнейшие выводы. Только необходимо понять, в чём именно кроется барьер производительности. Потому что можно передать в шейдер 100 мб данных, а можно всего лишь 10 мб, но в сжатом виде. Не всё можно реализовать аппаратно.

Comment: @OpenGLprogrammer Это конечно очень здорово, но я вам пытаюсь объяснить, что шейдер запускается для каждой вершины (!). И данные в такой шейдер в нормальном случае грузятся оптимальным способом из VBO, да и шейдера сами по себе параллелятся по типу kernel'ов в `OpenCL` - все-таки с `GPU` имеем дело.

Comment: @OpenGLprogrammer Мне кажется, ыы просто не представляете себе, насколько заоптимизирован современный графический пайплайн, а эти разговоры про `TRIANGLE_FAN` - это несерьезно.

*Вот если бы вы придумали какой-нибудь алгоритм ускорения процесса тесселяции, это было бы здорово.* А так, в 2011 году экономия треугольников на изотерических примерах с кругами кажется мне непонятной.

Comment: Круги – это примитивный  пример предполагаемой оптимизации. Любая оптимизация лишней не бывает. У вас есть возражения по поводу того, что круг выгоднее рисовать с GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, и насколько это в целом повышает производительность? Как её развить и повысить гибкость?

Comment: @OpenGLprogrammer **Любая оптимизация бывает лишней.** Пример с кругами - это не `hotspot` вашего приложения. Какой смысл оптимизировать то, что и так быстро рисуется? *Или, может быть, все ваши программы рисуют ТОЛЬКО круги?*

Есть общеизвестные способы повышения производительности графики, например, при написании своего движка - smart-фильтрующие *(переставляющие)* пайплайны, VBO, отсутствие `if'ов` в шейдерах, тесселяция вместо засылания миллионов полигонов в конвейер и тому подобные вещи.

Comment: @OpenGLprogrammer Возвращаясь к первоначальной теме - если вы сможете придумать, как соединить запакованные данные и вершинный шейдер эффективнее, чем сделано в современных конвейерах *(где уже применяются оптимизации при передаче данных и эти данные чаще всего имеют известный формат)*, то я с радостью вас выслушаю.

**Но я, например, не вижу, как это реализуемо.**

Answer (score 0):

Можно сэкономить на нормалях и текстурных координатах. На нормаль хватит 2 байта (2 координаты, 3-ю можно вывести из первых 2-х в самом шейдере), на текс. координаты одной 2D текстуры тоже 2 байта.
 Если вершины расположены по сетке и они находятся не очень далеко друг от друга, то можно тоже передавать их в виде целых чисел небольшой точности или half float.
 На уровне геометрического шейдера можно придумать что-нибудь ещё.